# Control the transactionSet in EDI Batching Service

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2013

I am using BizTalk Batching service generating some X12 files now, 
Now, For the outbounding messages, I am processing the messages one by one and then send to BizTalk Batching service to build the file. Problem is now the BizTalk will add ST/SE for every single message I send to Batching service, If I put 5000 records in the batching, it will generate a file with 5000 ST-SE .

I am wondering if there's a way to control the ST/SE pairs so I can, say, have 5 ST/SE in the file, each have 1000 records. instead of current 5000 ST-SEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity, you're getting 5000 ST/SE's because *you are sending 5000 ST/SE's*.  The Batching Service is not changing your messages in any way.

To restructure the message, you can intercept the batched output in an Orchestration or Pipeline Component and merge the Loops, at whatever level you want, into a single ST.  This would be a custom procedure.

Comment: Thanks Johns. I am considering merge the messages now. But what I am thinking is merge them before I send them to Batch service. It looks add an orchest to handle this ST/SE merge may be better than merge message before batching. Since I won't lost lots of messages just becuase one of record have edi validation issue.

Comment: Johns, I noticed another thread you replied on kind of same question.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0026611-b0dc-4af1-b899-13942f0eeffd/problem-batching-edi-message-into-single-stse-transaction?forum=biztalkediandas2https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c0026611-b0dc-4af1-b899-13942f0eeffd/problem-batching-edi-message-into-single-stse-transaction?forum=biztalkediandas2

Comment: For the approach of resequence into a single ST/SE after biztalk batching, Looks like an orchestration might be more reasonable. and since we also need re-generated the HL01 sequency number,  What I am thinking is loop through all transaction set nodes, and use a 2 to 1 mapping to merge 2 record into 1. The only concern of this is the size of accumulated message will be huge.  
  Do you have any other better solution?